# CCS PIC C: What is the difference between #INT_TIMER0 and #INT_RTCC?

Tags: interrupts, pic-ccs

In CCS PIC C Compiler, there are two interrupts and both are tied to Timer0 overflowing. These are called #INT_TIMER0 and #INT_RTCC. What does RTCC mean and is #INT_TIMER0 not sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I have always treated them interchangeably (one and the same thing).  Here's what CCS compiler manual says about this:

> #INT_RTCC ----- Timer 0 (RTCC) overflow
>   #INT_TIMER0 -- Timer 0 (RTCC) overflow

From the header file for PIC18F4550.h <sup>1</sup>

```
#define INT_RTCC                  0xF220
#define INT_TIMER0                0xF220
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Nothing particular about PIC18F4550.  I'm using it as an example, because it's nearest to me, because it's in the project that I'm currently working on.</sub>

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the RTCC interrupt might be intended for devices with a separate RTCC module, but for those which don't it just defaults to TIMER0 ...

Answer (score 0):

My recollection is that they are interchangeable.  You can use either when you code -- they are the same device.

From the PICC manual entry for set_rtcc:

> Function:  Sets the count value of a real time clock/counter. RTCC and
>   Timer0 are the same. All timers count up.  When a timer reaches the
>   maximum value it will flip over to 0 and continue counting (254, 255,
>   0, 1, 2...)